# Hardware failure?

Tags: boot, hardware, dvd

I am getting following errors when I boot my laptop. It takes a minute to load and the boots normally. I think this has to do with DVD drive. It is behaving very oddly for some time - it opens randomly while I am using the laptop. I am posting the error dmesg output for the error.

```
dmesg | grep ata2
    [    1.426670] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf361c000 port 0xf361c180 irq 41
    [    1.746067] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [    1.747462] ata2.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GU71N, LM00, max UDMA/133
    [    1.748888] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [    7.194342] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x5a90c00 action 0xe frozen
    [    7.194390] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
    [    7.194426] ata2: SError: { Proto HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B BadCRC LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }
    [    7.194475] ata2.00: cmd a0/01:00:00:00:01/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 2 dma 16640 in
    [    7.194556] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
    [    7.194581] ata2: hard resetting link
    [    7.918305] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [    7.921100] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [    7.921620] ata2: EH complete
    [    7.942708] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280801 action 0x6
    [    7.942751] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
    [    7.942775] ata2: SError: { RecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
    [    7.942810] ata2.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 7
    [    7.942889] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
    [    7.942913] ata2: hard resetting link
    [    8.262325] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [    8.265182] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [    8.265734] ata2: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 action 0x7 t4
    [    8.265776] ata2: irq_stat 0x40000001
    [    8.265798] ata2: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
    [    8.265824] ata2: hard resetting link
    [    8.582331] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [    8.583580] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [    8.583584] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   13.582510] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   13.902527] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [   13.905624] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [   13.906166] ata2: EH complete
    [   13.914998] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 action 0x6
    [   13.915041] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
    [   13.915064] ata2: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
    [   13.915093] ata2.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 8
    [   13.915174] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
    [   13.915199] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   14.234537] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
    [   19.234716] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   19.554743] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [   19.555998] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [   19.556003] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   19.556035] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
    [   24.554912] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   24.874940] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   24.878157] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [   24.878692] ata2: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 action 0x7 t4
    [   24.878734] ata2: irq_stat 0x40000001
    [   24.878757] ata2: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
    [   24.878783] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   25.194945] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   25.198189] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [   25.198194] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   30.195124] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   30.515143] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   30.518663] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [   30.518668] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   30.518702] ata2.00: limiting speed to UDMA/133:PIO3
    [   35.515323] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   35.835339] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   35.838999] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [   35.839040] ata2.00: TEST_UNIT_READY failed (err_mask=0x100)
    [   35.839044] ata2.00: disabled
    [   35.839053] ata2: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x880800 action 0x6 frozen t3
    [   35.839096] ata2: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
    [   35.839127] ata2: SError: { HostInt 10B8B LinkSeq }
    [   35.839155] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   36.155353] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   36.155373] ata2: EH complete
    [   37.484780] ata2: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
    [   37.484783] ata2: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
    [   37.484786] ata2: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
    [   37.484792] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   38.207429] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [   38.209445] ata2.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GU71N, LM00, max UDMA/133
    [   38.211007] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [   38.211544] ata2: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 action 0x7 t4
    [   38.211549] ata2: irq_stat 0x40000001
    [   38.211551] ata2: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
    [   38.211556] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   38.531439] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
    [   43.531602] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   43.851637] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [   43.854395] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [   43.854400] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   43.854406] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
    [   43.854408] ata2.00: limiting speed to UDMA/133:PIO3
    [   48.851809] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   49.171834] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   49.173104] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [   49.173108] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   49.173111] ata2.00: disabled
    [   49.173121] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen t3
    [   49.173123] ata2: irq_stat 0x08000002, interface fatal error
    [   49.173126] ata2: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
    [   49.173129] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   49.491852] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   49.491867] ata2: EH complete
    [   49.491883] ata2.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
    [   50.861794] ata2: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
    [   50.861799] ata2: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
    [   50.861801] ata2: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
    [   50.861807] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   51.587906] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [   51.589902] ata2.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GU71N, LM00, max UDMA/133
    [   51.591247] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [   51.591249] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   56.588060] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   56.908055] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
    [   56.909253] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [   56.909257] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   56.909261] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
    [   61.908264] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   62.232275] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   62.234860] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
    [   62.234863] ata2.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    [   62.234865] ata2.00: disabled
    [   62.234875] ata2: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280901 action 0x6 frozen t4
    [   62.234877] ata2: irq_stat 0x08000002, interface fatal error
    [   62.234879] ata2: SError: { RecovData UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
    [   62.234883] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   62.556286] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   62.556298] ata2: EH complete
    [   74.719794] ata2: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 action 0x7
    [   74.719834] ata2: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
    [   74.719859] ata2: hard resetting link
    [   75.037053] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [   75.053091] ata2: EH complete
```